# Issues running commands within BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

It's been quite a long time since I've written a BASH script so I'm a bit out of practice so forgive the poorly written structure :-)

I wrote a basic "prompt" script that'll add/delete SFTP user accounts. The script prompts the user for information when adding/deleting the account. When adding, it creates the account in the 'CHROOT' jail & adds a root mounted RO folder that contains image files.

There's 3 types of groups:

> 'staff' = These are users who are basically "Admins" & are allowed to access the server.
>
> > They have physical access to the server & have permission to make changes to it,
> > can create users, examine logs, are allowed to run SCP/SFTP, etc.
> > (HOME FOLDER: /home/chroot/home/$uid)
> > (FOLDER PERM: $uid:$gid)
> > (SHELL      : /bin/bash)

> 'users' = Users who are allowd to login but are not allowed passed their 'CHROOT' home. (i.e. Techs)
>
> > They are allowed to run "SFTP" *ONLY* to/from their own home directory.
> > They aren't allowed to access files outside of their home directory.
> > (HOME FOLDER: /home/chroot/home/$uid)
> > (FOLDER PERM: root:root)
> > (SHELL      : /bin/bash)

> 'sftpusers' = Users who *ONLY* have SFTP use.
>
> > They do NOT have access to be able to log into the server at all.
> > They are only permitted SFTP & only from within their home directory.
> > (HOME FOLDER: /home/chroot/home/$uid)
> > (FOLDER PERM: root:root)
> > (SHELL      : /bin/nologin)

When I run this script, 2 problems arose:

1. When adding the user, everything appears to work just fine.
   Account gets created in the proper directory; the base folders get
   created & mounted directories get mounted RO within the user's home
   directory; the user's "sftp" folder has the proper permissions; the
   user is added to the proper group selected.

**PROBLEM**: When choosing either "users" or "sftpusers" for the group, the home folder doesn't have the right permissions, as if the `"chown root:root /home/chroot/home/$uid"` command doesn't execute.

2. When deleting the user, everything appears to work just fine.
   Account gets deleted; the user's "sftp" folder gets removed.

**PROBLEM**: The mounted RO folder doesn't become unmounted, as if the `"umount -f"` command never executes, & the user's home directory never gets removed.

Can anyone point me to where I went wrong? (Please be gentle in your comments LoL)

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Notify user of incorrect selection
incorrect_selection() {
    echo "Option doesn't exist. Please try again."
}
menu_add_user() {
    clear;echo ""
    echo -e "\tADDING NEW USERS FOR SFTP"
    echo -e "\t========================="
    echo ""
    read -p " 1) What is the user's UID? " uid
    read -p " 2) What is the user's full name? " fname
    read -p " 3) What is the user's room number/cube? " room
    read -p " 4) What is the user's work phone #? " work_ph
    read -p " 5) What is the user's cell phone #? " cell_ph
    echo ""
    echo -e "\tPlease choose one of the following:"
    echo -e "\t==================================="
    echo -e "\t1) The user is a contractor"
    echo -e "\t2) The user will only be a SFTP user"
    echo -e "\t3) The user is local LAN MANAGEMENT"
    echo ""
    read -p "Enter your selection [1-3]: " member
    case $member in
        1 ) read -p "Enter the contractor's company name: " other
            other="(CONTRACTOR - ${other})"
            read -p "Will the user manage SFTP user access [y/n]? " mgr
            case $mgr in
                [Yy]* ) group='staff';;
                [Nn]* ) group='users';;
                * ) incorrect_selection;;
            esac;;
        2 ) group='sftpusers'
            other="(SFTP ONLY USER)";;
        3 ) read -p "Will the user manage SFTP user access [y/n]? " mgr
            other="(LAN MANAGEMENT)"
            case $mgr in
                [Yy]* ) group='staff';;
                [Nn]* ) group='users';;
                * ) incorrect_selection;;
            esac;;
        * ) group='sftpusers';;
    esac
    echo ""
    echo -e "\tPLEASE VERIFY"
    echo -e "\t============="
    echo -e "\tUser's UID: $uid"
    echo -e "\tUser's Name: $fname"
    echo -e "\tRoom / cubical location: $room"
    echo -e "\tUser's Work Ph: $work_ph"
    echo -e "\tUser's Work Cell Ph: $cell_ph"
    echo -e "\tUser will be placed into group: $group"
    echo -e "\tOther user information: $other"
    read -p "Is the above correct? " correct
    room=`echo "$room" | sed 's/,/|/g'`
    case $correct in
        [Yy]* ) echo -e "\tCREATING USER ACCOUNT..."
            if [[ $group -eq 'staff' ]] ; then
                echo ""
                echo -e "\tASSIGNING USER TO GROUP: [$group]"
                echo -e "\tCREATING USER ACCOUNT [$uid]..."
                sudo su -c "adduser --home /home/chroot/home/$uid --ingroup $group --disabled-password --gecos \"$fname,$room,$work_ph,$cell_ph,$other\" $uid"
                echo -e "\tCREATING USER DEFAULT DIRECTORIES - [sftp,Cisco]..."
                sudo su -c "mkdir /home/chroot/home/$uid/{sftp,Cisco}"
            elif [ $group -eq 'users' ] || [ $group -eq 'sftpusers' ] ; then
                echo ""
                echo -e "\tASSIGNING USER TO GROUP: [$group]"
                echo -e "\tCREATING USER ACCOUNT [$uid]..."
                # Create the user with the proper login shell based on group assignment.
                if [[ $group -eq 'sftpusers' ]]; then
                    sudo su -c "adduser --home /home/chroot/home/$uid --ingroup $group --disabled-password --gecos \"$fname,$room,$work_ph,$cell_ph,$other\" --shell /bin/nologin $uid"
                else
                    sudo su -c "adduser --home /home/chroot/home/$uid --ingroup $group --disabled-password --gecos \"$fname,$room,$work_ph,$cell_ph,$other\" $uid"
                fi
                echo -e "\tCREATING USER DEFAULT DIRECTORIES - [sftp,Cisco]..."
                sudo su -c "mkdir /home/chroot/home/$uid/{sftp,Cisco}"
                # THIS COMMAND IS NEEDED IN ORDER TO MAKE USER A SFTPUSER ONLY #
                sudo su -c "chown root:root /home/chroot/home/$uid"
            else
                echo ""
                echo -e "\tGROUP ($group) DOESN'T EXIST"
            fi
            echo -e "\tSETTING USER FOLDER PERMISSIONS..."
            sudo su -c "chown $uid:$group /home/chroot/home/$uid/sftp"
            sudo su -c "mount --bind /home/chroot/home/sftpuser/Cisco /home/chroot/home/$uid/Cisco"
            sudo su -c "mount -o remount,ro,bind /home/chroot/home/sftpuser/Cisco /home/chroot/home/$uid/Cisco"
            echo ""
            echo -e "\tCREATED USER ACCOUNT: [$uid]"
            sed "/END: $group/i $fname $other: $(printf '\t%.0s' {2})$uid <---- ACTIVE" SFTP_User_List.txt
            echo -e "\t============================";;
        [Nn]* ) echo "Re-enter the information..."
                menu_add_user;;
        * ) incorrect_selection;;
    esac
}
menu_delete_user() {
    clear;echo ""
    echo -e "\tDELETING USERS FROM SFTP ACCESS"
    echo -e "\t==============================="
    echo ""
    read -p " 1) What is the user's UID to be deleted? " uid
    read -p " 2) Do you want to save any files in the user's folder? " sfiles
    echo ""
    echo -e "\tPLEASE VERIFY"
    echo -e "\t============="
    echo -e "\tDelete user [UID]: $uid"
    echo -e "\tElected to save files: $sfiles"
    read -p "Is the above correct? " correct
    case $correct in
        [Yy]* ) case $sfiles in
            [Yy]* ) sudo su -c "umount -f /home/chroot/home/$uid/Cisco $uid"
                    sudo su -c "deluser --force --backup-to /home/chroot/home/sftpuser/$uid --remove-all-files $uid" 2>/dev/null ;;
            [Nn]* ) sudo su -c "deluser --quiet --force --remove-all-files $uid" 2>/dev/null ;;
                esac;;
        [Nn]* ) menu_delete_user;;
    esac
    # MARK USER REMOVED IN LIST FILE
    echo ""
    echo -e "\tDELETED USER ACCOUNT: [$uid]"
    sed -i "/$uid/ s/ACTIVE/REMOVED/" ./SFTP_User_List.txt
    echo -e "\t============================"
}
press_enter() {
    echo ""
    read -p "Press enter to continue..."
    clear
}
until [ "$selection" = '0' ]; do
    clear;
    echo ""
    echo -e "\tCREATE or DELETE SFTP USER MENU"
    echo -e "\t==============================="
    echo -e "\t 1 - Add a new user"
    echo -e "\t 2 - Delete an SFTP user"
    echo -e "\t 0 - Exit"
    echo ""
    read -p "Enter selection: " selection
    case $selection in
        1 ) clear; menu_add_user; press_enter;;
        2 ) clear; menu_delete_user; press_enter;;
        0 ) exit;;
        * ) clear; incorrect_selection; press_enter;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: A quick suggestion: try to change `sudo su -c` with `sudo bash -c`

Comment: I don't understand the need for the `sudo su -c` commands. Why not simply `sudo` or `sudo -u`? You say "as if the chown/umount command were not executed". Have you considered surrounding these commands with `set -x` and `set +x` for debugging? You should also check if they were successful. You try to unmount a directory as user $uid, which seems to be non-root. That fails except if the filesystem is marked as `user` in `/etc/fstab`. I do wonder why no error message is issued, though.

Comment: @berndbausch : Based on what I read the `sudo su -c` command allows a you to run the command as root but still forces them to need to use their RSA token or password. (although I guess, technically, I could add them to the "sudoers" file and allow the commands. I just didn't want to go through all that). I just find it odd that all the other commands work just fine, except those.